# How to define elements in Jemmy library with the usage of ComponentChooser?

Tags: automated-testing, java, java-gui, jemmy

I am researching possibility of testing Java GUI application with Jemmy library.

Elements in application are defined by constructors like:

```
JFrameOperator mainFrame = new JFrameOperator("Main window title");
JButtonOperator flsButton = new JButtonOperator(mainFrame, "Button name");
```

Possible constructors are (depends on element, but here is the common set):

```
JSomeComponentOperator(ContainerOperator cont)
JSomeComponentOperator(ContainerOperator cont, int index)
JSomeComponentOperator(ContainerOperator cont, String title)
JSomeComponentOperator(ContainerOperator cont, String title, int index)

JSomeComponentOperator(ContainerOperator cont, ComponentChooser chooser)
JSomeComponentOperator(ContainerOperator cont, ComponentChooser chooser, int index)
```

The first four constructors are easy to use: you should specify:

- `cont` - container of the new object (parent object)
- `title` - text on the object
- `index` - index of element on the page (e.g. index counted through all JButtons)

But I could not find any reference on usage of `ComponentChooser chooser`.

Can anyone give some example on its usage?

Here is the dump of a button I'd like to define this way (e.g. by using tooltip text cause it is unique):

```
<component operator="org.netbeans.jemmy.operators.JButtonOperator">
    <property name="Class" value="javax.swing.JButton"/>
    <property name="Default button" value="false"/>
    <property name="Height" value="39"/>
    <property name="Showing" value="true"/>
    <property name="Tooltip text" value="Accounts"/>
    <property name="Visible" value="true"/>
    <property name="Width" value="39"/>
    <property name="X" value="1"/>
    <property name="Y" value="1"/>
    <property name="toString" value="javax.swing.JButton[,1,1,39x39,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle$XPEmptyBorder@554712c3,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=jar:file:/C:/asu_eirc/59.1.4/icons.jar!/icons/32/abacus.gif,disabledIcon=sun.swing.ImageIconUIResource@2fc53144,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=null,defaultCapable=false]"/>
</component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my example of `ComponentChooser` usage:

```
JButtonOperator flsButton = new JButtonOperator(mainFrame, new ComponentChooser() {
                public boolean checkComponent(Component comp) {
                    if (comp == null)
                        return false;
                    else if (!(comp instanceof JButton))
                        return false;
                    else if (((JButton)comp).getToolTipText().equals("Accounts"))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }

                public String getDescription() {
                    return "searching for JButton instance with ToolTipText='Accounts'";
                }
            });
```